# How do you pass authentication information from one .net Web Api method to another

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

Using the .net Web Api and Forms authentication, I have an Api method that makes a second Api call. The first Api method is being called from javascript and I can get the Identity of the currently logged in User using the GetUserPrincipal method:

```
private void Put(int id, object value) {
    var principal = ControllerContext.Request.GetUserPrincipal();
    ....
    var responseMessage = new HttpClient().PutAsync("/api/secondapicontroller/", null).Result
    ....
}
```

However, when that method makes the chained internal Api call, the GetUserPrincipal returns an empty object, no Identity, not authenticated etc.:

```
private void Put(int id, object value) {
    var principal = ControllerContext.Request.GetUserPrincipal();
    ....
}
```

How would you pass the authentication information from the first Api method to the second.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to include cookie from the request in the HttpClient - if authentication works on both. Here explains a bit about [setting the cookie in the HttpClient](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lv-LV/winappswithcsharp/thread/3724d52e-c92a-45c7-8ed5-8e76a244d80b).

Comment: Was there supposed to be a link there?

Comment: Sorry! Yes, forgot. There you go.

Comment: Didn't really help. Thanks though.

Comment: Didn't really help. Thanks though. I was able to add cookies to the client:
    new HttpClient().DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(...)
And I can see those cookies on the second Api method, but the GetUserPrincipal is still empty. Looking at dominick baier's post describing the architecture (http://www.leastprivilege.com/ASPNETWebAPISecurity2IdentityArchitecture.aspx) while not providing any particular solution, makes it seem like maybe the original calling context is getting lost on the second request.